# Show first child of element without a specific class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to show the first child of an element which does not have a class of "submitted"

So something like

```
$('#menu li:first-child:not(".submitted")').show();
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li class="submitted">stuff here</li>
   <li class="submitted">stuff here</li>
   <li>stuff here</li> <!-- This one needs to be shown -->
   <li>stuff here</li>
   <li>stuff here</li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas??

Comment: As you can see you'll get different answers based on how your question is interpreted. Maybe add an example? Do you want the first of the set of children that doesn't have that class? Or, for an element which doesn't have that class, its first child? Or the first child of some element iff that first child doesn't have that class (and nothing otherwise)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$('#menu li:not(.submitted):first')
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('#menu li:not(".submitted"):first').show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WDx3M/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#menu li:first-child').not(".submitted").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu li:not(.submitted) > :first')
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rZrzu/)

Answer (score -1):

yes it does work.You can have look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/gFutw/

Comment: what is the solution required and what are u trying to explain in your example. Please elaborate.

Comment: when the question was posted initially ,the thought was to find the first child not having the class name "submitter".After the question was modified it turned out that the requirement was to find the first element without the class "submitted" inside a container